# How to get the values of each row from multiple rows with same ID?

Tags: mysql

i have the following table in MySQL:

[image: Table]

I need to select the data as:

[image: Table2]

Comment: That is really a weird way to store data in RDBMS. I understand that you are creating a hierarchy here. But it's not needed when you already have separate columns for `subject`,`chapter`,`topic..` and so on. If you are storing all those values in a single column than only the hierarchy(with `id`) make sense.

Comment: The database structure of an existing system is already as the first table. And my requirement is to generate a report with structure as the second table. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `Is there a way to do that?` Maybe. But `Is there an easy or efficient way to do that?`  I don't think so.